# Unity Container RegisterInstance method not found

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

I was using Unity version 4.0.1 and I updated to the version 5.8.11 
I had this line working before the update

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        this.Container.RegisterInstance<Manager>(new Manager());
    }
}
```

There was no problem with `RegisterInstance` Method because I was using the `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace. But after the update, the code is not compiled anymore. I really searched and I found that there was a break for the compatibility between the two version, but I can not figure out the solution.

**update**
using the `Unity` namespace did not work. I still received the same compile time error

> The type 'IUnityContainer' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f'.

**update**
updating Unity without updating Prism still cause the same problem, but interestingly, updating prism without updating Unity does not cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The namespace is just `Unity` in version 5.8.11:

```
using Unity;
```

...but you can't update just Unity without updating Prism. Your version of Prism is not compatible with this version of Unity.

Comment: @HakamFostok: Did you try to update Unity but not Prism...?

Comment: Did you see my update? You can't update Unity without updating Prism? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes I did, but did you see the second update on my question? problem appears when I updating both Prism and Unity, but Updating just Prism (without updating Unity) is fine

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't update Unity. Update Prism and use the version of Unity that is compatible with that Prism version.

Comment: This is a really bad thing, So Prism is forcing me to use an old version of Unity and I can not update it.

Comment: Not without updating Prism to a version that is indeed compatible with the version of Unity that you are updating to.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: in some way, yes and this is why I upvoted, but I will not accept this because I want others to be still interested in this question, so maybe they could provide me with some workaround for the problem

Comment: There is no workaround besides re-writing Prism. Why do you need to update Unity in the first place?